# Can't import a class from an external project Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

"I am working on an API with Spring Boot (JDK 11, Spring Boot 2.7). The project contains only the implementation and the endpoints. The other project, called 'persistence,' holds the entities and the repositories.

I am trying to import classes from the 'persistence' project into the API project. I have already added the dependency and built the JAR. I also checked the external libraries, and the classes are present there. However, when I attempt to import them, I receive suggestions with the correct package names, but pressing 'Enter' doesn't result in any action.

when I manually write the import statement, it seems that IntelliJ can't locate the dependency in the '.m2' folder. This situation is quite wierd."

pom of the API project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoapisender</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoAPI</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

            <!--  this is the project 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-for-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    

        

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

pom of the persistance project :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-for-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>persistence</name>
    <description>persistence-for-a</description>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>





    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

what i tried :

-cleaning the cash in my Ide.
-checking project structure .
-clean and install .
-deleting the folder in .m2

what i suspect :

-maven version problem (3.8.1).
-Ide config.

Comment: can you build the project without intellij - just mvn clean install at the command line? And does your project persistence even compile? I cannot see an artifactId there in your pom

Comment: yes i tried mvn clean install no errors also yes the persistence compile

Comment: sorry didnt see your pom for persistence completely.. does your mvn at the command line use the same maven and jdk version as intellij?

Comment: cmd uses mvn 3.8.6 and jdk 11 and intelij uses mvn 3.8.1 ,  jdk11 ,SDK JDK 19

Comment: mvn therofre should not be the problem, but what do you mean by " jdk11 ,SDK JDK 19"

Comment: its fixed ! turned out that the issue is related to intelij (project structure must have the persistence location included in module config)